# RDP behind "black box" router/gateway stopped working

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, rdp, windows-server-2000

Let me begin by describing this (weird?) network configuration...

Two organizations sharing an office: one has a large network with Win2k3 Server Domain Controller, which seems to intercept inbound RDP connections.

My small organization has our PCs and a Win2k Server Domain Controller connected to their network, though we do not use any of the resources of their Server or Domain, except -- the way I understand it -- our PCs gateway to Internet via their router. (We manually assign our own IPs which has recently been the cause of other problems...  Suddenly there was an IP conflict and our small "sub-network" stopped working properly until I changed one of our machine's IPs to some new unused IP.)

Recently our gracious hosts made some changes/upgrades to their net somehow and now one of our users who previously was able to RDC to his workstation from outside the office, cannot.

It's a strange situation but basically it seems that it is really bad etiquette for us to actually bother their IT support staff in any way with these problems -- I am allowed to ask like 1 question a year and I already hit this year's quota! ;) And to ask them to make a change on our behalf is just a major *faux pas* to the point of being out of the question! So I am left to try and figure this out "from the inside", with limited capabilities.

To make it slightly trickier, I have only remote access to *our* server for which I am using LogMeIn. I can't even RDP to a workstation from that desktop for some weird reason.  (which is another issue I am trying to troubleshoot and related to [my first post](https://serverfault.com/questions/162595/configure-rdp-listening-ports-map-ports-to-internal-machines-on-win2k-server).)

I don't care if I have to reconfigure everything from scratch.... Any info or pointers to site/page which can help me get this sorted and set-up properly functioning?? Is it even possible to do so without some sort of intervention on the part of the gateway network admins?

TIA!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a tricky situation. Here's my advice:

Don't try to fight the powers that be. Use LogMeIn on all of your computers that need to be accessed remotely. LogMeIn requires no firewall modifications, no router modifications, and should be completely transparent to your "host" company.

Comment: Thanks for the response! My desire to see an RDP solution stems mainly from the classic "well it *was* working" + the user will probably want to transfer files, and unless I read it wrong, LogMeIn is going to charge $70 a year for that. So, we have a nontechnical user - also CEO! ;) - who is going to be singing that tune of "well it *was* working", as well as a refrain of "why do we now we have to pay for something that has been working, free, for almost 10 years?!" ;) + general "why is 'X' different?" whines. ;) I'm soon to investigate further... Will post back anything of interest. TY again!

Comment: I hear you and you make some very good points. My only point is that you may be fighting a losing battle with the other company. If they're as difficult as they sound it may be cheaper and easier in the long run to just use LogMeIn. Either that or get your own switch, router, firewall, and internet connection and be done with them altogether.

Comment: FYI we went the LogMeIn route. Turns out user actually prefers to just work on the remote desktop, so no issue w/file transfers and we are fine with the free version. As for the other Co. involved, it's not even a matter of them being difficult; it's more that they do us a favor by letting us operate on the fringes of their physical space (was being sincere when I said "gracious"); it's just a matter of displaying supreme etiquette. Our CEO not only condones but sets the example. The sublet situation is not ideal but it cuts costs. TY for response! Sry for late accept!

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution that works for you.